# How to find current date & time in dataweave?

Tags: datetime, dataweave

I am converting a XML file to CSV file using dataweave , where i want current date & time from payload. So, how to get it?

Comment: try `now as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}` OR  `date : now as :datetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"}`

Comment: i am transforming a dynamic value, where to append above syntax...ProgramLastDate : payload.ns0#Worker_Sync.ns0#Header.ns0#Current_Effective_Time date now as :datetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"}....this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use   `now`
for eg. `ProgramLastDate : now`
or can be used`

## [server.dateTime.format('yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSSs')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"ProgramLastDate" : now as :string {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}` for getting system date and time, but as per your code I think you wanted to get date time from xml element Current_Effective_Time. If you are receiving Current_Effective_Time in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" format, You can use

```
ProgramLastDate : payload.ns0#Worker_Sync.ns0#Header.ns0#Current_Effective_Time  as :datetime {format:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"} as :string {format:"dd-MM-yyyy"}
```

Hope this helps.